# How to float An icon button and elevatedButton in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm still learning Flutter

[image]

I want the "close" iconbutton in the top left to be floatable while the rest content scrolling, as well as not to exceed the safearea, only the content can exceed.

Also the same thing for EleveatedButton, i want it to be floatable and fixed in the bottom.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:icon_decoration/icon_decoration.dart';
import 'package:training/models/images_instance.dart';

class CustomDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;

  const CustomDialog({super.key, required this.selectedIndex});

  @override
  State<CustomDialog> createState() => _CustomDialogState();
}

class _CustomDialogState extends State<CustomDialog> {

  ValueNotifier<double> animationValue = ValueNotifier<double>(0.0);

  double calculateItemPrice(int itemCount, double originalPrice) {
    return itemCount * originalPrice;
  }

  void addItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      imagesInstances[index].itemCount++;
      animationValue.value = 0.5;
    });
  }

  void removeItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (imagesInstances[index].itemCount > 1) {
        imagesInstances[index].itemCount--;
        animationValue.value = -0.5;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(
                imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].imageString!,
                width: size.width, // Stretch to the entire width
                height: size.height * 0.4,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10, left: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].imageTitle!,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].imageDescription!,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 80,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'EPG ${imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].itemPrice.toString()}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: 0,
                        top: 10,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(1, 3),
                                  blurRadius: 4,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    removeItem(widget.selectedIndex);
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.remove,
                                    color: imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex]
                                        .itemCount > 1
                                        ? const Color(0xffE66219)
                                        : const Color(0xffFECDB4),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                AnimatedSwitcher(
                                  transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
                                    final   offset = Offset(0, animationValue.value);
                                    return   SlideTransition(
                                      position: Tween<Offset>(
                                        begin: offset,
                                        end: Offset.zero,
                                      ).animate(animation),
                                      child: child,
                                    );

                                  },


                                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].itemCount}',
                                    key: Key(
                                        '${imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].itemCount}'),
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                IconButton(
                                  color: const Color(0xffE66219),
                                  // Default color
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    addItem(widget.selectedIndex);
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30, right: 15, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: const Offset(12, 0),
                          child: Transform(
                            transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(-1, 1, 1),
                            child: const DecoratedIcon(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.chat_bubble,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              decoration: IconDecoration(
                                border:
                                IconBorder(width: 3, color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'Any special requests?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    const Text(
                      'Add note',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 15, horizontal: 15),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange[900],
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Add to basket',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      Text(
                        'EPG ${calculateItemPrice(imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].itemCount, imagesInstances[widget.selectedIndex].itemPrice!)}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context, int selectedIndex) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    isScrollControlled: true, // Use isScrollControlled
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: CustomDialog(selectedIndex: selectedIndex),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Hope someone help me

Comment: I added the answer please check

Comment: I will try it today and tell you what happened

Comment: Not working, the close icon and ElevatedButton didn't float and are scrolling with the rest content

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try something like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
            child: Text("ElevatedButton"),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

It looks like this

[image]

You can also run it here [working example](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zok806rdok90?split=50&lazy=false&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart:892-2520)